# Installing nodejs with node-gyp without internet

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install, node-gyp, renovate

I want to check if there is a way to bypass node-gyp not to download the header when it is running the npm install. Currently my environment only have npmjs whitelisted.

```
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path /opt/node/lib/node_modules/renovate/node_modules/better-sqlite3
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command sh -c prebuild-install || node-gyp rebuild --release
npm ERR! prebuild-install warn install read ECONNRESET
npm ERR! gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
npm ERR! gyp info using node-gyp@10.0.1
npm ERR! gyp info using node@20.11.1 | linux | x64
npm ERR! gyp info find Python using Python version 3.9.18 found at "/usr/local/bin/python3"
npm ERR! gyp http GET https://nodejs.org/download/release/v20.11.1/node-v20.11.1-headers.tar.gz
npm ERR! gyp WARN install got an error, rolling back install
npm ERR! gyp ERR! configure error 
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack FetchError: request to https://nodejs.org/download/release/v20.11.1/node-v20.11.1-headers.tar.gz failed, reason: read ECONNRESET
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack at ClientRequest.<anonymous> (/opt/node/lib/node_modules/renovate/node_modules/minipass-fetch/lib/index.js:130:14)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack at ClientRequest.emit (node:events:518:28)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack at _destroy (node:_http_client:875:13)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:83:21)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! System Linux 5.10.210-201.852.amzn2.x86_64
npm ERR! gyp ERR! command "/opt/node/bin/node" "/opt/node/lib/node_modules/renovate/node_modules/.bin/node-gyp" "rebuild" "--release"
npm ERR! gyp ERR! cwd /opt/node/lib/node_modules/renovate/node_modules/better-sqlite3
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node -v v20.11.1
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v10.0.1
npm ERR! gyp ERR! not ok
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: /home/node-py/.npm/_logs/2024-03-19T07_43_14_775Z-debug-0.log
```

Comment: try other node versions